# Joomla Strict Standards Error

Tags: standards, strict, joomla3.1

I am installing an extension in Joomla 3.1. It's working fine but on every page the extension is assigned for it is showing error " **Strict Standards: Declaration of JSJobsController::display() should be compatible with JControllerLegacy::display($cachable = false, $urlparams = Array) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SysMind\administrator\components\com_jsjobs\controller.php on line 25** "

The code is -

```
class JSJobsControllerJsjobs extends JControllerLegacy
{
    function __construct()
    { 
        //This curly bracket is the line 25 in my code.
        parent :: __construct();

        $this->registerTask('add', 'edit');
    }   

    function editsubcategories()
    {
        JRequest :: setVar('layout', 'formsubcategory');
        JRequest :: setVar('view', 'application');
        $this->display();
    }

    function edit()
    {
        $cur_layout = $_SESSION['cur_layout'];
        JRequest :: setVar('view', 'application');
        JRequest :: setVar('hidemainmenu', 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false){} in your JSJobsControllerJsjobs class ?

Answer (score 3):

Inside `com_jsjobs\controller.php` you probably have a method `display()`.

You need to update it's declaration with:

`public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = array())`

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell your JSJobsController display method, that you don't use any urlparams with this declaration:

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
```